# How to add a value to a lookup field in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

Hi I have two Lists in sharepoint 2007.
I have a lookup column in on list which looks the other field.
I want to use the sharepoint object model to add an item to the second list.
How to i set the lookup field value. (The value is already in the other list).?

```
SPListItem Employee = web.Lists["Employee"].Items.Add();
Employee["Name"] = account.Name;
Employee["Department"] = <lookup value must come here>
Employee.Update();
```

Comment: This also Helpful [Get and Set a SharePoint Lookup Field Values Using SSOM C#](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40271.get-and-set-a-sharepoint-lookup-field-values-using-ssom-c.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookup fields will contain a combination of the row's id and the value of the column to display, separated by `:#`, in your case that could be `1:#HumanResources` or `12:#Engineering`.

So to reference a lookup simply setting the id won't be enough, instead the above mentioned string needs to be set. Luckily SharePoint provides the class `SPFieldLookupValue` that does exactly this:

```
var department = web.Lists["Department"].GetItemById(1);
var employee = web.Lists["Employee"].Items.Add();
employee["Name"] = account.Name;
employee["Department"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(department.ID, department.Title);
employee.Update();
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be necessary. If I check the value of employee["Department"] after setting it, it is simply set to "1". And if I just do employee["Department"] = "1"; employee.Update(); it works fine.

Comment: @xr280xr, huh, interesting. [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem(v=office.12).aspx) that _"A Lookup field contains a string in the form ID;#VALUE, where ID is the list item ID and VALUE is the value of the lookup field in the other list."_ Are you sure that the item in the other List is being referenced correctly, when doing it your way?

Comment: I had the impression that it was `;#` and not `:#` for the separator. Am I missing something?